# Make DIVs vertically equally spaced and show spans right below the input text fields

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML and its associated CSS,

1. the vertical gap between  "#text1-div", "text-area1-div", "text-area2-div" and "#text2-div" are uneven.
2. the `<span>` elements are shown on the right hand side of the text inputs. I want them to be shown just below the respective input fields.

I changed as follows:

```
.form-div div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-div span {
  display: block;
}
```

However, they seem to be not working.

How can I do that?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.menu-strip {
  background-color: #4285f4;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-strip ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-strip li {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.menu-strip a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.angry-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "text form" "footer footer";
  grid-gap: 20px;
  height: 90vh;
}

.header-div {
  grid-area: header;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 10px;
  /* reduce the padding */
  background-color: #4285f4;
  color: #FFF;
}

.text-div {
  grid-area: text;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.form-div {
  grid-area: form;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4285f4;
}

.form-label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.form-input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #4285f4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 220px);
}

.form-textarea {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #4285f4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.submit-button {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #4285f4;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4285f4;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.footer-div {
  grid-area: footer;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #4285f4;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

fieldset {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #3F51B5;
}

fieldset legend {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3F51B5;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.error-message {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

.has-error .error-message {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.error-blink {
  animation: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

#table1 {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#table1 td,
#table1 th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#table1 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#table1 tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#table1 th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #table1 {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  #table1 th,
  #table1 td {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="menu-strip">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('jobs_table') }}">Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="angry-grid">
  <div class="header-div">App Title</div>
  <div class="text-div">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="form-div">
    <form id="contact" method="post" action="">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Submit a new job</legend>
        <div class="input-box" id="text1-div">
          <label class="form-label" id="project-name1">Project name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="Project name" class="form-input" id="text1" autocomplete="off" value="project-name-1" />
          <span id="error-msg-text1"></span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="input-box" id="text-area1-div">
          <label class="form-label" id="protein-seq1">Protein Sequence:</label>
          <textarea name="protein-sequence" class="form-textarea" id="text_area1">Protein Sequence~1</textarea>
          <span id="error-msg-text-area1"></span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="input-box" id="text-area2-div">
          <label class="form-label" id="sec_struct1">Secondary Structure:</label>
          <textarea name="secondary-structure" class="form-textarea" id="text_area2">Secondary Structure~1</textarea>
          <span id="error-msg-text-area2"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box" id="text2-div">
          <label class="form-label" id="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" class="form-input" id="text2" autocomplete="off" value="abc@xzy.com" />
          <span id="error-msg-text2"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="submit-button">
          <button type="submit" class="btn" id="submit_button">
              <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
              Submit
            </button>
          <input type="button" name="Reset" class="btn" value="Reset" />
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-div">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/java_script/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: you have 2 strays `<br>` included to create extra spacings. I would suggest the usage of Flexbob with `flex-direction: column` instead. Then control the spacings with the `gap` attribute. Alternatively use `display: block` on the spans to give them a block behavior (which then displays them below other elements instead of being inline.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
#contact span {
  display: block;
}

label#protein-seq1 {
    margin-top: 4.66px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.menu-strip {
  background-color: #4285f4;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-strip ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-strip li {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.menu-strip a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.angry-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "text form" "footer footer";
  grid-gap: 20px;
  height: 90vh;
}

.header-div {
  grid-area: header;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 10px;
  /* reduce the padding */
  background-color: #4285f4;
  color: #FFF;
}

.text-div {
  grid-area: text;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.form-div {
  grid-area: form;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4285f4;
}

.form-label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.form-input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #4285f4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 220px);
}

.form-textarea {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #4285f4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.submit-button {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #4285f4;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4285f4;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.footer-div {
  grid-area: footer;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #4285f4;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

fieldset {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #3F51B5;
}

fieldset legend {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3F51B5;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.error-message {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

.has-error .error-message {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.error-blink {
  animation: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

#table1 {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#table1 td,
#table1 th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#table1 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#table1 tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#table1 th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #table1 {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  #table1 th,
  #table1 td {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="menu-strip">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('jobs_table') }}">Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="angry-grid">
  <div class="header-div">App Title</div>
  <div class="text-div">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="form-div">
    <form id="contact" method="post" action="">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Submit a new job</legend>
        <div class="input-box" id="text1-div">
          <label class="form-label" id="project-name1">Project name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="Project name" class="form-input" id="text1" autocomplete="off" value="project-name-1" />
          <span id="error-msg-text1"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box" id="text-area1-div">
          <label class="form-label" id="protein-seq1">Protein Sequence:</label>
          <textarea name="protein-sequence" class="form-textarea" id="text_area1">Protein Sequence~1</textarea>
          <span id="error-msg-text-area1"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box" id="text-area2-div">
          <label class="form-label" id="sec_struct1">Secondary Structure:</label>
          <textarea name="secondary-structure" class="form-textarea" id="text_area2">Secondary Structure~1</textarea>
          <span id="error-msg-text-area2"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box" id="text2-div">
          <label class="form-label" id="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" class="form-input" id="text2" autocomplete="off" value="abc@xzy.com" />
          <span id="error-msg-text2"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="submit-button">
          <button type="submit" class="btn" id="submit_button">
              <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
              Submit
            </button>
          <input type="button" name="Reset" class="btn" value="Reset" />
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-div">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/java_script/index.js"></script>
```